# How does a processor talk to a serial device?

Tags: assembly, serial-port, x86-64

Does an external circuit place the information from the serial device into a known location in ram for the processor to read? If so, how? What circuits and chips are involved?

Would data coming from a serial device trigger a processor interrupt? If so, how? Again what circuits and chips are involved?

For example I have looked at chips such as the ICL3221CAZ-T, which would appear to give me two pins to connect to my serial device, and two to talk internally. It would appear these are refereed to as "TTL/CMOS compatible transmitter Inputs". Using a simple Intel 8086 processor, how would I get these things to talk?

How does this all link up with the standard c library input stream?

Comment: Yes serial ports are classically accessed via io ports and an interrupt.  See [serial ports on osdev](https://wiki.osdev.org/Serial_Ports). You don't need to implement that sort of standard COM port though.

Comment: IO ports on the processor itself?

Comment: Yes. See also [port mapped i/o](https://embeddedartistry.com/fieldmanual-terms/port-mapped-i-o/) and _Chapter 19 Input/Output_ in the _Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual Volume 1: Basic Architecture_

Comment: But for memory mapped IO the processor addresses it as if it were any other memory location. What chips are used to accomplish this? Somehow I must be converting my single bit width sequence of 1s and 0s into a nBit register

Comment: @Tyler Old computers had a dedicated UART chip for that (such as the 8250 and 16550).  With newer computers, this circuitry is integrated into the southbridge.  The interface has remained the same though.

Comment: With even older computers, this functionality was implemented in TTL logic using a shift register and some counters to generate a clock.

Comment: On x86 CPUs, so-called "I/O ports" are nothing but special memory addresses which are accessed using special instructions. From the hardware perspective, accessing an "I/O port" works the same way as accessing some RAM memory location.

Comment: *"Serial device"* is an ambiguous term.  Serial transfers are used by many interfaces, e.g. I2C, SPI, SATA, and even Ethernet.  Seems like the term missing from your vocabulary is UART.

Answer (score 3):

> Using a simple Intel 8086 processor ...

Some background information first:

In principle, a simple 8-bit CPU (like the 6502 or the 6800) writes the value 0x12 to the address 0x3456 by setting the 8 wires of the "data bus" to the combination that represents the number 0x12 and the 16 wires of the "address bus" to the combination that represents the number 0x3456. Then the CPU outputs a voltage pulse on the "write" wire. When the RAM receives this pulse, it writes the value 0x12 to the address 0x3456.

Reading from RAM works similarly: The CPU only sets the wires of the "address bus" and generates a pulse on the "read" wire. Then the RAM sets the 8 wires of the "data bus" to the combination that represents the value stored in address 0x3456.

Of course you can also attach different ICs to the CPU so maybe addresses 0 to 0x3FFF is RAM and the addresses from 0x4000 to 0x40FF are a serial device.

ARM CPUs (as you find them in many cell phones or on the Raspberry Pi) still work this way.

Please note that the 8086 is not as simple as you think: It is much more complex than the 6800 or the 6502!

x86 CPUs have a special address range which is called "I/O ports". From software perspective, accessing this address range is done differently than accessing addresses in the RAM. However, from the hardware perspective this is nothing but a different address range and accessing this addresses works just like accessing addresses in RAM.

> What circuits and chips are involved?

First of all you have a "chip select" logic. This logic consists of simple gates (such as AND or NOR gates) but also more complex logic ICs (like the 74LS138). The job of this logic is to generate signals that "select" a certain chip based on the address.

Example: If the address is in the range 0 to 0x3FFF, the logic sets the wire that controls the RAM to "low"; otherwise it sets this wire to "high". If the wire is "high", the RAM knows that the data transfer is intended for another chip.

For serial data transfer, an UART IC (like the 8250) is used. Such an IC typically covers an address range with multiple addresses. By writing values to some addresses you control the IC (e.g. the baud rate). By writing values to a certain address you send data.

These chips already generate and receive a serial signal.

Unfortunately, these ICs use 0V as "0" and 5V as "1" but the RS-232 standard uses -9V as "1" and +9V as "0".

A "transceiver" (like the ICL3221CAZ-T) is used to convert the 0V/5V serial signal to a +9V/-9V serial signal.

In modern computers there are larger chips (e.g. the "south bridge") which contain the functionality of a lot of chips in the early computers.

> Would data coming from a serial device trigger a processor interrupt? If so, how?

This depends on the type of UART chip and how it is connected to the CPU.

In an 8086 PC, the UART chip will set the "interrupt" output to a certain voltage. This is recognized by the "programmable interrupt controller" (like the 8259). This chip will then send some signals to the 8086 CPU; these signals contain the information which interrupt (the one of the serial IC) has been triggered.

> How does this all link up with the standard c library input stream?

It depends on how your computer is built. If you have some computer that does not use an "I/O port" address range, you can access the UART chip by directly writing to some address. Example:

```
*(unsigned short *)0x4003 = 0x13;
```

This is the case for many microcontrollers today. It was also standard for older, non-x86-compatible computers.

If you have a PC, the UART is accessed using the "I/O port" address range that requires special instructions. The C library for many MS-DOS compilers as well as the library for the Linux kernel have such instructions. They are not "standard C" functions but they are OS specific.

Compilers for Windows don't have these instructions because Windows uses a protection mechanism which does not allow programs accessing the "I/O port" address range.

If you want to write an operating system and you want to access the UART, you might have to use assembler.

Comment: You sir, know your stuff. Thank you very much!!